# Fastest way to match 2d arrays of characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, multidimensional-array, generator

There are two arrays that display a map(around 100x100) and a small template (part of this map less than 20x20). It is necessary to find all possible entrances of template (some boolean function for each possible matching).
For example some small map can be presented with:

```
#.#.#
.....
#####
```

Now I store it in list of strings. And nested loops works slowly.
What is the fastest way to work with such types of arrays? Is it possible to make generator of pairs and work with it? Or should I use built-in string functions for faster results?

```
def read():
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    l = []
    for _ in range(n):
        l.append(input())
    return n, m, l

n_m, m_m, base = read()
n_d, m_d, dust = read()


def check(i, j):
    if i == '#' and j != '#':
        return False
    return True


def solve(y, x):
    ans = True
    for i in range(n_m):
        for j in range(m_m):
            ans &= check(base[i][j], dust[i + y][j + x])
    return ans

cnt = 0
for i in range(n_d - n_m + 1):
    for j in range(m_d - m_m + 1):
       cnt += 1 if solve(i, j) else 0
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a solution you already have so we can see what might possibly be slowing it down?

Comment: What does "entrance of template" mean? If my guess is correct and you're trying to find if it is contained (or how many times it is contained), you should look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-an-array-is-subset-of-another-array-set-1/)

Comment: @Axe319 yes, please.

Comment: @edd it mean, that you should count how many times small template matching the map.